# WINSCP doesn't resume

Tags: ftp, winscp

WINSCP is supposed to resume FTP transfers when the file part already exists, except it seems to only do that occasionally, seemingly at random. At other times, it will completely replace the file.

How do I fix this? Is there more reliable FTP software that won't completely waste my data and time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instruct WinSCP what to do with already existing files:

- Transfer Settings Dialog: [Other Options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#other)

  > In the *File mask* you can specify [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) to select/deselect files (or file types) and directories for the transfer. The option also selects files for [synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full) and [*Keep remote directory up to date*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) function.
  >
  > Press *Edit* button to edit the file mask in [File mask dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editmask).
  >
  > The *New and updated files only* checkbox makes WinSCP ignore files in source directory for which there exist file in the target directory with the same filename and the same or newer timestamp. The option is not available for uploads with SCP and S3 protocols. Make sure WinSCP can correctly [convert timestamps](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/timestamp) from local conventions to remote server conventions and vice versa before using the option.
  >
  > Check *Exclude hidden files* to exclude hidden and system files from transfer and synchronization.
  >
  > Check *Exclude empty directories* to exclude empty directories from transfer and synchronization.
- File Transfer Resume: [Common Problems](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#common_problems)

  > If you want to resume your transfer, you must use the same source file version as the interrupted transfer. If you do not, your target file will include the source file’s previous version and its current version. For automatic resume, if the partial file is bigger than the source file, WinSCP will display error and disallow resume.
  >
  > If the target file exists and it is not write-able, but the target directory is, the file will may be transferred anyway with automatic resume. The error overwriting the file will occur only after the transfer finishes. It is because the file is first transferred into temporary file.

Comment: None of this has been helpful. I am talking about large individual files, so file masking is no use here. I have already read that "common problems" page and confirmed that I am doing everything correctly (according to them).

Comment: Well, you might want to have a look into different software solutions then

Comment: I figured as much. Any suggestions with transfer resume?

Comment: FileZilla always worked fine for me, but I don't know about resuming downloads

Comment: I came from FileZilla, it doesn't. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Check the modified time of the remote and local file. It seems that winscp will refuse to resume a file if the remote file is newer. I can not find a way to force resuming in winscp.

Try filezilla 2.2.32, it will provide an option to resume anyway.